# An property similar to primeness for an ideal in commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let  $I$ be an ideal of  a commutative ring $R$ with identity
such that if $r^n\in I$ for some $r\in R$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
then $r^2\in I$. Is this ideal a prime ideal of $R$? Or is this
kind of ideals famous? Or is there any equivalent donation for such a property for $I $?

Comment: It is not generically prime. But prime implies it. Consider $(x^2)\subset k[x]$.

Comment: Are you aware of semiprime (aka radical) ideals? They have the property that $r^n\in I$ implies $r\in I$. Your condition is more relaxed, and I have not seen it used.

Comment: Basically you are asking for ideals that contain the square of their radicals, aren't you?

Comment: It is clearly if $ I$ contains the square of its radical, then $I $ has the mentioned property. Why is the convers true?

Comment: Google  the definition of “n-absorbing”.